# mobile-chrome-apps using cordova plugin

Tags: android, cordova, google-chrome-app

I'm trying to get a polyfill for the issue with input[type=file] on Android 4.4.

chrome.fileSystem.chooseEntry shows the dialog but not the callback.

Anyhow this look(s)/(ed) promising:

https://github.com/cdibened/filechooser

but using the "cca plugin add..." instead of "cordova plugin add..." fails.

Other posts recommend doing everything through the cca toolchain.

What is the best approach?

What are other developers doing about the issue with input[type=file] on Android 4.4?

Thanks, Nic

Answer (score 2):

`cca plugin add` forwards off to `cordova plugin add`, making sure that the paths, versions, etc are correct, so you were right to use that.

The reason this plugin fails to install is because it is bundling the `android-support-v4.jar` library, which we already also install.

The resolution is simple: all plugins should not bundle external libraries, and should instead use a `plugin.xml` `<dependency>` tag on a single common plugin to add these external libraries.

[We provide a bunch of these](https://github.com/MobileChromeApps) plugins for Google libraries, [including for android-support-v4](https://github.com/MobileChromeApps/cordova-plugin-android-support-v4).

[I've filed an issue for us to better handle this error](https://github.com/MobileChromeApps/mobile-chrome-apps/issues/144), but the resolution is to reach out to that plugin author and make the change, or fork fix and issue a pull request.

If you are not able to do this, let me know and I will add it to our backlog!

Comment: Thanks mmocny. Just saw your post. Prior to this I succeeded installing the plugin by removing the existing android-support-v4.jar library temporarily. Following the plugin authors installation instructions I hit a roadblock with "import your.package.name.R" steps. Is there a simple polyfill for the Android 4.4 input[type=file] issue? Is the official  chrome stance that ChooseEntry is broken in mobile-chrome-apps?

Comment: One alternative to try: install org.chromium.fileSystem and call chrome.fileSystem.chooseEntry()