# mobile-chrome-apps - chrome.fileSystem.chooseEntry in Android 4.4

Tags: android, cordova, google-chrome-app

I have just started with mobile-chrome-apps - but have been doing desktop chrome-apps for some time.

Is the callback in chrome.fileSystem.chooseEntry broken?

Some have talked of [errors](https://github.com/MobileChromeApps/mobile-chrome-apps/issues/62) but all I see is: the dialog gets evoked, after choosing the file the callback is left wanting.

Can someone confirm this is broken?
Are there permissions other than filesystem needed?

I have started reverting to using a input[type=file] but the Android 4.4 webkit issue is causing a road-block.

Thanks,
Nic

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is broken.

Yes, this is broken (excuse me, [WorkingAsIntended](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=62220)) permanently.
The reasoning is that it was not public, documented API.

There is apparently a workaround using [cdibened/filechooser](https://github.com/cdibened/filechooser), but I have no experience to back it up. You may run into [some problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23056859/mobile-chrome-apps-using-cordova-plugin).

Comment: Thanks Xan. Yes I was the poster of "some problems"... Just for the record I have promising results with [ram.kulkarni.filechooser](http://ramkulkarni.com/blog/file-chooser-dialog-for-phonegap-application/); just ripping out dependency on jqueryMobile now and binding with angularjs...

Comment: As a follow-up to this, the chooseEntry method was the only proprietary api that I was using from chrome. I was doing a lot of loading of images and audio using base64 resources. The chrome-mobile-app was crashing after a few minutes (possible memory leak?). I fell back to phonegap only and the hierarchical cycling of images has been running for hours now (in an emulator - Genymotion). Have not carried out end-to-end testing on device but looks promising...